# Docker build keeps failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, docker, ubuntu, pm2

I am trying to deploy my node.js application using docker. I keep getting this error:
`the command /bin/sh -c npm run build --prefix backend returned a non-zero code: 1`.

The node.js is written in typescript. Here is my docker file:

I don't know what I'm doing wrong but it is my first time of using typescript with docker for deployment

```
## multi stage system
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY package*.json ./ 

COPY backend/package*.json backend/

RUN npm run install-backend 

RUN npm run backend-build


## this is stage two , where the app actually runs
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./ 

COPY backend/package*.json backend/ 

RUN npm run install-backend --only=production


COPY ./build ./build

RUN npm install pm2 -g

USER node

CMD ["pm2-runtime", "ecosystem.config.js"]

EXPOSE 5000
```

Here is my root package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "chickeneat",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "install-backend": "npm install --prefix backend",
    "backend-dev": "npm dev --prefix backend",
    "backend-production": "npm production --prefix backend",
    "backend-build": "npm run build --prefix backend"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

And here is my server package.json file

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn src/server.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "production": "node src/build/src/server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Kingsley Okoro <kingswebapp>",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "ts-node-dev": "^2.0.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.4"
  },
 
}
```

I was asked to provide the entire log: Here it is. The OS is linux on Ubuntu

```
npm run build --prefix backend


> backend@1.0.0 build
> tsc

Version 4.9.4
tsc: The TypeScript Compiler - Version 4.9.4

COMMON COMMANDS

  tsc
  Compiles the current project (tsconfig.json in the working directory.)

  tsc app.ts util.ts
  Ignoring tsconfig.json, compiles the specified files with default compiler options.

  tsc -b
  Build a composite project in the working directory.

  tsc --init
  Creates a tsconfig.json with the recommended settings in the working directory.

  tsc -p ./path/to/tsconfig.json
  Compiles the TypeScript project located at the specified path.

  tsc --help --all
  An expanded version of this information, showing all possible compiler options

  tsc --noEmit
  tsc --target esnext
  Compiles the current project, with additional settings.

COMMAND LINE FLAGS

--help, -h
Print this message.

--watch, -w
Watch input files.

--all
Show all compiler options.

--version, -v
Print the compiler's version.

--init
Initializes a TypeScript project and creates a tsconfig.json file.

--project, -p
Compile the project given the path to its configuration file, or to a folder with a 'tsconfig.json'.

--build, -b
Build one or more projects and their dependencies, if out of date

--showConfig
Print the final configuration instead of building.

COMMON COMPILER OPTIONS

--pretty
Enable color and formatting in TypeScript's output to make compiler errors easier to read.
type: boolean
default: true

--target, -t
Set the JavaScript language version for emitted JavaScript and include compatible library declarations.
one of: es3, es5, es6/es2015, es2016, es2017, es2018, es2019, es2020, es2021, es2022, esnext
default: es3

--module, -m
Specify what module code is generated.
one of: none, commonjs, amd, umd, system, es6/es2015, es2020, es2022, esnext, node16, nodenext
default: undefined

--lib
Specify a set of bundled library declaration files that describe the target runtime environment.
one or more: es5, es6/es2015, es7/es2016, es2017, es2018, es2019, es2020, es2021, es2022, esnext, dom, dom.iterable, webworker, webworker.importscripts, webworker.iterable, scripthost, es2015.core, es2015.collection, es2015.generator, es2015.iterable, es2015.promise, es2015.proxy, es2015.reflect, es2015.symbol, es2015.symbol.wellknown, es2016.array.include, es2017.object, es2017.sharedmemory, es2017.string, es2017.intl, es2017.typedarrays, es2018.asyncgenerator, es2018.asynciterable/esnext.asynciterable, es2018.intl, es2018.promise, es2018.regexp, es2019.array, es2019.object, es2019.string, es2019.symbol/esnext.symbol, es2019.intl, es2020.bigint/esnext.bigint, es2020.date, es2020.promise, es2020.sharedmemory, es2020.string, es2020.symbol.wellknown, es2020.intl, es2020.number, es2021.promise/esnext.promise, es2021.string, es2021.weakref/esnext.weakref, es2021.intl, es2022.array/esnext.array, es2022.error, es2022.intl, es2022.object, es2022.sharedmemory, es2022.string/esnext.string, esnext.intl
default: undefined

--allowJs
Allow JavaScript files to be a part of your program. Use the 'checkJS' option to get errors from these files.
type: boolean
default: false

--checkJs
Enable error reporting in type-checked JavaScript files.
type: boolean
default: false

--jsx
Specify what JSX code is generated.
one of: preserve, react, react-native, react-jsx, react-jsxdev
default: undefined

--declaration, -d
Generate .d.ts files from TypeScript and JavaScript files in your project.
type: boolean
default: `false`, unless `composite` is set

--declarationMap
Create sourcemaps for d.ts files.
type: boolean
default: false

--emitDeclarationOnly
Only output d.ts files and not JavaScript files.
type: boolean
default: false

--sourceMap
Create source map files for emitted JavaScript files.
type: boolean
default: false

--outFile
Specify a file that bundles all outputs into one JavaScript file. If 'declaration' is true, also designates a file that bundles all .d.ts output.

--outDir
Specify an output folder for all emitted files.

--removeComments
Disable emitting comments.
type: boolean
default: false

--noEmit
Disable emitting files from a compilation.
type: boolean
default: false

--strict
Enable all strict type-checking options.
type: boolean
default: false

--types
Specify type package names to be included without being referenced in a source file.

--esModuleInterop
Emit additional JavaScript to ease support for importing CommonJS modules. This enables 'allowSyntheticDefaultImports' for type compatibility.
type: boolean
default: false

You can learn about all of the compiler options at https://aka.ms/tsc

The command '/bin/sh -c npm run backend-build' returned a non-zero code: 1
kingsley@kingsley-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/code/chickenEat$
```